# Hosting an Access database on SharePoint

Tags: javascript, ms-access, sharepoint, adodb

I'm trying to use an Access database as the database for a SharePoint site and connect to it via an ADODB ActiveX Object in JavaScript.

I have tried to use SharePoint lists instead of Access but the information retreival was painfully slow. Unfortunately, due to the bureaucracy of large companies, I am unable to use anything other than client-side code: SharePoint and Access.

I have got this working to a point; however, the problem I am having is updating the data when more than one user tries to access the SharePoint site at once -- only the first user's changes are saved. The second user can make changes and they show on the second user's screen until the browser is closed and then the changes are gone.

I have tried moving the database to a shared network drive and connect to it from there and it works fine, so the problem must be with SharePoint, not with my code or the database.

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated as I have spent the last 2 days trying to work this one out!

Comment: `I'm trying to use an Access Database as the database for a Sharepoint site` are you saying you want to not use SQL server to host a sharepoint site but deploy the site with Access instead? This doesn't sound like it is going to come close to working.

Comment: No, sorry, the SharePoint site is hosted on an SQL server, however the site I have created needs to store and access a lot of data and doing this with the SharePoint lists was incredibly slow. The data is now in an Access database which is stored on SharePoint.